# Password reference in open SFTP in WinSCP

Tags: vba, winscp

I am trying to input the password from a string variable `str` into the connection string to WinSCP In the below connection, I would like to refer `str` instead of password since the password needs to be changed every month. It's tedious to update the password in every code where the below connection is used. So I am trying to update the password in an Excel cell and `str` contains that value.

```
WinSCP.com
open sftp://username:password@address
```

So far, I tried:

- Using `username:&str`

  But I get an *"Access denied"* message in WinSCP.
- ```
  Dim str As String
  str = Range("A20").Value Const CMD_WINSCP As String = _
       "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com /Command ""open sftp://walvesv:" & str & "@d7lxpsasg01.logistics.cat.com/ -hostkey=""""fingerprint"""""" ""put local remote"" ""exit"""""
  ```

  but I get:

  > Constant Expression Required

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An expression with a variable is not a constant, so you cannot assign it to a `Const`. Use `Dim` to declare a *variable* instead.

```
Dim CMD_WINSCP As String
CMD_WINSCP = "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com /Command ""open sftp://walvesv:" & str & "@d7lxpsasg01.logistics.cat.com/ -hostkey=""""fingerprint"""""" ""put local remote"" ""exit"""""
```